# Linking Objective-C project on Windows

Tags: objective-c, linker

i have compiled two classes (Etudiant.m) and (main.m) and i obtain successufully the two .o files (Etudiant.o) and (main.o).
However when linking with this command :

```
gcc -c -o prog -Wno-import Etudiant.o main.o -lobjc
```

i got this :

```
gcc.exe : Etudiant.o : linker input file unused because linking not done

gcc.exe : main.o : linker input file unused because linking not done
```

can anybody help me to find out how to solve linking issues ??
THX in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `-c`. That tells the gcc frontend not to perform the linking. So, instead of

```
 gcc -c -o prog -Wno-import Etudiant.o main.o -lobjc
```

just do

```
 gcc -o prog -Wno-import Etudiant.o main.o -lobjc
```

Comment: Hi, i already tried your suggestion but i got :

cannot find -lobjc 
collect2 : Id returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Malek: you need to tell the linker where the Objective-C runtime library is.  put `-L<path to folder containing Obj C runtime library>` before the `-lobjc`

Comment: Hi, itried to find the runtime library, i guess it`s under C:\GNUstep\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.0\include so i tried this command as you said but i still have the same error above :((

Comment: so, can you help me there :))